# How can I find questions that I haven't voted to close?

Tags: support, search

I'd like to find a way to get a list of questions that have a particular tag and that

- have zero answers
- aren't closed
- and that **I have not voted to close**

It's easy to use the [advanced search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to satisfy all but the last criterion (`[tag1] answers:0 closed:no`). Is it possible to filter on the last criterion?

To clarify, I'm not hunting for questions to close. I'm hunting for questions to **answer**, and the ones that I've voted to close are typically ones where I've suggested to the OP in comments how they need to improve/clarify their question before I can answer it — so I don't want to waste time looking at them.

Comment: I must admit, *hunting* for questions to close seems like the *wrong* idea. Though, as shown in the [Search help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching), there's no "I haven't VTC'd" option, and you can't use [SEDE](//data.stackexchange.com) as votes aren't in the dataset (for obvious reasons).

Comment: @ThomA final close votes are in SEDE: PostHistory -> TypeId = 10 -> Text column. Pending votes aren't in SEDE, nor in the API.

Comment: With scripting against the SE API, you can call https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/no-answer-questions#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=r&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true   and then for each question call https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/question-close-options#id=76373733&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true  to see if `is_retraction` == true because that means you have voted. This does require you authenticate against the API so it is not trivial. Over on Stack Apps you might find scripts to put you in the right direction: https://stackapps.com/questions